Are comoving distances time-independent?
A comoving reference frame expands along with the universe, factoring out the effect of the Hubble expansion. Suppose a galaxy has a redshift $z = 1$ and its comoving distance DM is $11 \,\mathrm{Gly} = \mathrm{const}$. This is also the distance we measure today.
After 1000 years the distance to that galaxy is measured again:

will its comoving distance still be $11 \,\mathrm{Gly}$?, or
will the comoving distance be larger than $11 \,\mathrm{Gly}$ since the reference frame has expanded, stretching the distances? Then, how can I calculate this new comoving distance?


Yes, the comoving distance $\chi$ between objects that move with the Hubble flow does not change in time. Formally, it is defined as follows
$$ \chi=\int c \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{a(t)} .$$
As $\chi$ is normalized by the scale factor, the latter telling us how much the universe has expanded; thus, $\chi$ factors out any changes in distance due to expansion.
The relation between proper distance $d$ and comoving distance at a time $t$ can be written as
$$d(t)=a(t) \chi$$
and the scale between $d$ and $\chi$ is set such that $d(t_{\rm today}) = \chi(t_{\rm today})$, which means that $a(t_{\rm today}) = 1$.

Thank you, this is well understood. As I see, the relevant point is the setting a(today) = 1 and what "today" means.  So is it also correct to say that cosmologists in the future (1000 years from now) are free to choose "their" today to set a = 1 to measure their comoving distance Chi (z) to the galaxy and declare it constant? However the object has moved with the Hubble Flow and is then farther away than the present comoving distance of 11 Gly.

One cannot arbitrarily set a value for $\chi(t_{\rm today})$. This has to be set such that as $a(t = 0) \rightarrow 0$, $d(t=0) \rightarrow 0$. This means that if in the future we set $a(t) = 1$, then $d(t)$ and hence $\chi(t)$ should have a different value.
